# Galaxy S4 taking values from MDPI?

Tags: android

I want to use separate `values` for each density, so I created different `values` folders for each one,

```
values
values-ldpi
values-mdpi
values-hdpi
values-xhdpi
values-xxhdpi
```

in each of the `strings.xml` file I wrote the density (for `values-xxhdpi` i have a string with the text "`xxhdpi`"), but when I run this on GS4, I get the "`mdpi`" string,

I also did create separate `layout` folders, but always taking `layout-mdpi` density

any clue of what might be going on ?

Comment: the default value is 'standard', so it definitely takes mdpi value

Comment: Are you sure all your folders have right permissions, they are not simlinks or any other thing that could prevent them to be put in the final apk ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit funny to me to define layouts according to density and not size. Drawable and other similar resources depend on density, but layouts depend on size.

See here : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

For values, you could give it a try with values-normal, values-large, etc.

I write this although what you did is supposed to work according to this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9639280/693752

Also, this resource is interesting to you : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

---- UPDATE ----

Look at this answer from [GodFather](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20521720/693752

> (Note that density qualifiers are even fuzzier -- -mdpi will be used
>   for any device density, in the absence of a better match, as density
>   qualifiers are designed to be used only on drawable directories, where
>   Android can apply resampling algorithms. Using density qualifiers on
>   anything other than drawables and maybe dimension resources is a code
>   smell.)

Comment: thank you very much for your time, although I read that S4 is of a NORMAL screen, then again so is GALAXY ACE, so the problem still persists, how can I differentiate  between them ?

Comment: I can't see a use case where you need to change strings displayed according to density, on size yes, but density, it really bugs me.

Comment: I was trying to make an XXHDPI layout, but it ended up using an MDPI one, so I used strings to see where the problem is, kind of a debug trick that's all

Comment: Again, I can't see how a layout can depend on density. It should depend on size.

Comment: hmm I see, so here is a straight question: how can I differentiate between layouts of a galaxy ace, and a galaxy s4 (besides working with mdpi and xxhdpi, I have no clue how to do it), thanks a lot !

Comment: If both devices have same size (or size range) then trying to distinguish them will lead you to some over-specific layouting. What are you gonna do next, have a different layout for each single Android phone on earth. That might take time. If there is really a difference in size between the 2, the there must be a better qualifier than just "normal", maybe something like "sw540dp", something like this.