# How to maintain size of different values folders for different screen sizes

Tags: java, android, android-layout, screen-density

different folders like values-small, values-large, values-normal, values-xlarge, how to place dimension for different folders.

My dimension file like:[please see my dimension file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ndMF.png)

Now how to place these dimension in different values folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to calculate dimensions:

**320 -> 0 -> 1**

**360 -> 25% -> 1.25**

**480 -> 50% -> 1.5**

**600 -> 75% -> 1.75**

**720 -> 100% -> 2**

Android’s way of dealing with this diversity: http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/

Android provides basic structure to support these devices by putting them in different density buckets i.e. ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi.

ldpi (0.75x)
mdpi (1 (baseline))
hdpi (1.5x)
xhdpi (2.0x)
xxhdpi (3.0x)
xxxhdpi (4.0x)

Density conversion factor for density buckets are as follows:
**ldpi: 0.75**

**mdpi: 1.0 (base density)**

**hdpi: 1.5**

**xhdpi: 2.0**

**xxhdpi: 3.0**

**xxxhdpi: 4.0**

If mdpi is 60 px, for hdpi 60*1.5/1 & for xhdpi 60*2.0/1 and so on.**strong text**

Comment: no its not. Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639219/android-hdpi-mdpi-ldpi-for-values-folder & follow Kai Wang answer.

Comment: i have checked but not getting ration between values folders.